# Expand div closes when pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this chat,
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Frmez

```
$(function() {
    $('.textarea-chat').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13 && ! e.shiftKey) {
            $(this.form).submit()
        return false;
       }
});
});
```

Updated code ^

But one problem with it is that if you input a text to send away to the chat and press enter, the chat window closes, it should stay open but I can't figure out how

Comment: you are submitting a form, it refreshes the whole page. you need to use ajax

Comment: How could i implement that with ajax so when i press enter it submit the form? I updated with the form submiting code

Comment: thats the thing, you do not submit any form. you are creating managed http requests and pull out the information you need, and append to the chat window. submitting the form will always refresh your window. or alternatively, you can set a cookie "chat_open" with value "true" or "false" whenever you open/close the chat, and on page load just open the chat if value is true.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this.form).submit()
```

This actually submits the `<form>`. You're probably getting the error "**Please use POST request**" because by default  it uses GET. It doesn't like being sent a query string, so it gives that error. You can POST stuff to it, but nothing will happen.

In order to POST stuff to it, you need to use Ajax. See [**docs**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

For example:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function () {

    var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; //handle form input by your script

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(), //serializes the forms elements
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data); //show response
        }
    });

    return false; //avoid executing actual submit of the form
});
```